# Hand-Spray Bidet Connection didn't work due to smaller existing pipes

Tags: plumbing

just received my hand spray bidet set i ordered online. After trying to connect the set, the existing pipes found on the installed bidet are smaller than the T-valve connecters. Both the female thread and the main water supply pipe. Can anyone please help with what type of connections i might need to install it properly. The images below might show exactly what i am facing. Many thanks

[image]

Comment: Your best bet is to take the existing supply hose and the T to your local store and find a combination of adapters that will allow you to connect them. While there are standards, there are more than one, and it's difficult for us to know which ones apply to you. Since you haven't given any make/model info for anything, even the nicest person here couldn't go look them up for you, so you'll have to put in the leg-work.

Comment: Although I agree with freeman that looks like the size for a “toilet” valve at the toilet the valve. The other end is probably a standard sink supply the hose would be like a 3/8 to 1/2”  or it could be 1/2 to 7/8 it’s hard to guess from a photo but I believe something like that is what you need to connect to the water supply.

Answer (score 1):

Look for something like this [compression fitting](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-1-2-in-OD-Compression-x-3-8-in-MIP-Brass-Adapter-Fitting-800959/207176460?MERCH=REC-_-searchViewed-_-NA-_-207176460-_-N) in the plumbing department. It's hard to guess the sizes by the picture.